# Storing customer specific details in MYSQL? Without new tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking at storing customer details upon registering for my service, the service in question is a booking system, each user needs to have his/her own calender system which keeps records of all bookings (arrival data/time, name , price etc) i can envision a way of storing all this unique user information in a single table linked by only userID?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `room_number` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `arrival` date NOT NULL,
  `depart` date NOT NULL,
  `nights` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Each user would need to store this information? surely i would need to create a whole new table for each user? (Which i know is just plain slow and wrong).

Comment: No, you would just insert new records into the table for each user.  The table should probably have a column for `userID`.

Comment: Surely there could be potentially thousands of intertwined user bookings in the table? and cause slowdown?

Comment: SQL is designed to manage large quantities of data in tables.  Thousands of rows is not a large quantity of data (in most cases).

Comment: Ok great! makes sense :) Feel free to make that into an answer i can accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to store a separate table for each user (except under some very specific requirements which are rather unusual).  Your table is missing a `userId`.  Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `room_number` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `arrival` date NOT NULL,
  `depart` date NOT NULL,
  `nights` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (UserId) references users(UserId)
);
```

Don't worry about the number of rows in the table.  SQL is designed to handle millions of rows for most applications.  In fact, splitting the data among multiple tables would introduce some major problems with performance (notably partially filled pages) that could greatly reduce performance.

Comment: I would becareful with that last statement. SQL is also designed for joining so lets not have a table with hundreds of columns (I know that's not what you meant but the OP may interpret that)